# A simple hashing-array-loop, I get error warnings even though it works, why is that?

Tags: arrays, loops, perl, hash

I have prepared a short loop that looks like this:

```
@array = ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
$count=0;
print "@array\n";
foreach $string(@array){
    $number=$count++ +1 ;
    $string{$link} = $number;
    print "$string\n$string{$link}\n";
}
```

It should come out as

```
a
1
b
2
```

...
and so on.
It works but when I print it out on the terminal, I get warning messages:

```
Use of uninitialized value $link in hash element at ./hashing_an_array.pl line 11.
Use of uninitialized value $link in hash element at ./hashing_an_array.pl line 12.
a
1
Use of uninitialized value $link in hash element at ./hashing_an_array.pl line 11.
Use of uninitialized value $link in hash element at ./hashing_an_array.pl line 12.
b
2

...
```

etc

Why do I get these messages? I just wanted to know so that even though it works, I am sure I know what I am doing.

Comment: `use strict;` would have told you that the variable `$link` is never defined. From your code I'm guessing you wanted to bind each element of `@array` to `$link` in turn, so try with  `for my $link (@array) { ... }` instead

Comment: Unrelated: `$count++ + 1` is equivalent to `++$count`.

Comment: so $link is undefined, which in context of requiring a string as a key in the hashref, perl interprets as empty string.
Therefore, on each iteration of the loop, it stores the current value in the hashref at key `''`. Because it's quite likely that this is unintentional, perl also emits a warning that it has done that.

You'll end up with a hashref with one key (`''`) and the latest value put there.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you never assigned a value to $link so it's default value is undef.  Trying to use undef as a hash key generates a warning message because it's invalid.

Read perldata http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the other answers `$link` is undeclared and you should `use strict;` which would tell you this:

```
Global symbol "$link" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $link"?)
```

The following snippet is probably something like what you were after:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = qw(a b c d e);

my $count = 0;

my %link;

foreach my $string (@array) {
    $count++;
    $link{$string} = $count;
    print "$string\n";
    print "$link{$string}\n";
}
```

Although you should probably rename your hash and iteration variable to something that better reflects your intent, like for example using `%count_for` and `$letter` if you were doing letter counts.

Comment: Alternative explanation: `$string{$link}` was supposed to be `$link{$string}`, which would fit with the loop variable being `$string`.

Comment: True, but I think using descriptive names like `%count_for` and `$letter` is the real solution :)

Comment: Descriptive, but misleading, since `%count_for` doesn't really store word counts. In fact, the code as given doesn't need a hash at all.

Comment: Yea well I don't really get the intent of what the op is doing here. We could obviously play golf and reduce this to almost nothing. All I know is he is storing a number in association with a letter of the alphabet, so perhaps `%position_in_alphabet` and `$index` ... The point is to use best practices around variable and hash names such that the names make the intent clear.

Comment: But yea I think I will change it to your suggestion, its probably more like what was intended.